# Should POST and PUT handlers do pre flight check for 404?

Tags: rest, sql

When implementing `GET` on a resource is makes sense to respond with `404` if the resource cannot be found. For `POST` and `PUT` verbs it is a little more complicated.

To respond with `404` in that case I would need to do some kind of pre flight check. First do a `SELECT` in the database, check if there is a matching row, if not, respond with `404`. But due to concurrent users there is no guarantee that the following `UPDATE` sql command will affect any rows.

Is it good practice to implement a pre flight check for resources in a REST API even if there is no guarantee that the request will be processed successfully anyway?

Comment: transactions are a thing

Comment: But how does that help in this case? Can I expect the exception from a failed transaction to tell me whether it failed because of a concurrently deleted or modified row? 404 is only appropriate in the former.

Comment: HTTPS error codes don't have to be *precisely* correct.  They're already not a comprehensive list of things that can go wrong anyway.  They're certainly not precise enough to tell you *why* a page was not found.

Comment: And what @Ewan is pointing out (more or less) is that the entire transaction succeeds or the entire transaction fails.  Once again, the HTTP Response Code doesn't have anything to say about *why.*

Comment: "Can I expect the exception from a failed transaction to tell me whether it failed because of a concurrently deleted or modified row?"  You might want to consider `409  Conflict` if that's a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, I think your question has roots in the common misuse of HTTP verbs.

## [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)

It's common to equate a `PUT` to an `UPDATE` in an RDBMs but it's actually more like an 'UPSERT' (i.e. update or insert if not present).

So as pointed out by Robert Harvey in comments on another answer, at first glance, it doesn't make sense to return a 404 not found in the case that you understand what kind of resource is being updated (or it's parent).  Consider the following URI:

```
https://domain.com/{root}/{parent}/{child}
```

So given the above it makes sense to return a 404 if you try to `PUT` against a `root` or `parent` that don't exist and if these are fixed, then that's likely what a decent framework will do.  If `child` doesn't exist, then we can create it.  However, there are some caveats.

Allow me an aside: Suppose you do allow clients to create resources with `PUT` as described above.  But lets suppose multiple users get to create off of the same root/parent path.  What should happen if one user tried to `PUT` to a resource created by another (unaffiliated) user?  There are two possibilities here: they have made an error such as trying to create an new resource or they are purposely trying to do something bad.  In either case, you don't want to allow that so you can return a `403` (forbidden) error.  But you are also allowed to return a `404` in the case that you don't want to give away info about whether that path exists.  But if you only return a `201` when a path doesn't exist, you again leak information.  This suggests that `404` could be used in this kind of scenario.  It also brings into question whether such a scheme is a good idea.  If you make a user/client identifier part of the path, you can avoid such accidental collision in the first place.  I won't say it never makes sense to go about things this way but it does potentially make it harder to distinguish between error scenarios on the client.

### But what if I don't want to let users create their own resources with `PUT`?

No problem: you don't have to.  Just because the spec says `PUT` can create or update doesn't mean you are forced to create any URI they send on a `PUT`.  It should be apparent that you can create rules around what URIs can be created with `PUT` against a path and one valid rule is 'none'.  Some error codes that might work for that are [`400` or `422`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329229/should-i-return-an-http-400-bad-request-status-if-a-parameter-is-syntactically).  And in the scenario above I made the argument that a `403` or `404` might also make sense.  Personally, I would avoid `404` here and use a 'bad input' response to make it clear that you aren't allowing creation of resources with `PUT`.

## [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

There's also a bit of confusion around `POST`.  While it's somewhat aligned with the concept of an `INSERT`, there's one aspect that I think a lot of people miss: the path in a `POST` request doesn't refer to the resource being created.  It's the path of the parent resource.  That is when you `POST` to

```
https://domain.com/{root}/{parent}
```

you are asking to create a new resource

```
https://domain.com/{root}/{parent}/{child}
```

and the identifier `child` is created by the server (although nothing says you can't have the client specify that in the content of the request.)

So in the context of your question, it doesn't make sense to return a `404` when the child doesn't exist because you are asking the server to create it and it shouldn't be part of the URI anyway.  However, if the parent resource doesn't exist, it makes perfect sense to return a `404` in that case as the URI would be asking to create a child of a non-existent resource.

To conclude, I would suggest avoiding the use of `404` with `PUT` and `POST` to indicate the lack of a child entity under here because it a little confusing at best and potentially just plain wrong.  It does make sense to use `404` to indicate that the parent path is non-existent or not accessible by the client.

Comment: "it doesn't make sense to return a 404 when the child doesn't exist because you are asking the server to create it and it shouldn't be part of the URI anyway. However, if the parent resource doesn't exist, it makes perfect sense to return a 404" very good comment" that makes a lot of sense. As a side note I have been debating whether PUT is worth implementing at all and just let my POST handler differentiate between Id property being set in body or not. I realize PATCH may be more appropriate in some cases but my framework does not support it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

I feel safe in saying that there is a large consensus amongst *experts* against using 404 to indicate that the object your API is looking for in its database was not found.

The main issue is that you will also get 404 when your webserver or client is misconfigured, or you simply mistype the domain.

The second is that you often don't want to throw an exception when a resource is not found, but html libraries will often throw exceptions on receipt of a 404 code.

However, If you want to use 404 for this purpose the implementation is simple enough even for an "attempted update against non existing resource".

- Begin a transaction
- Check for existence of the resource
- If its not there, return 404 and roll back transaction
- If it is there, continue with update and commit transaction

There is also the perhaps more optimal 'run sql and check number of rows affected' but the result is more open to interpretation.

**Alternatives to 404** (note this part is only for those who want an explanation of the first sentence)

Basically it comes down to the design of your code. You want to avoid forcing the user to check whether the method they just called succeeded or not. This allows them to write clear, simple code.

So. Exceptions when you can't recover, but more importantly, methods designed never to throw exceptions.

So if I'm trying to load objects that might not exist, Help me out with a method which recognised that "that doesn't exist" is a valid result of the call, not an exceptional circumstance.

If I'm trying to update an Object, think about how the system should handle it being deleted while I've had it open. Maybe you can just create object that don't already exist, or maybe updating sets where the is no match is fine.

In code a get function might return a null, an update might return number of rows affected. These can be represented as "null" or 0 rather than an error code.

Comment: Can you provide sources for your claim that there is a large consensus amongst experts against using 404 for this situation?

Comment: well at least 5 people agree :) but if you search for similar questions and blogs you will see this question comes up frequently and the various pros and cons are discussed at length.

Comment: I wouldn't take the upvotes as agreement as it is unrelated to the question and you do answer it quite well. That being said, my experience is actually the complete opposite of the "large consensus", both in my actual field of work and on most articles or blogs I have read. I also can't say your arguments convinced me, but I'm willing to stay open if you have any other sources that could enlighten me.

Comment: I've added a bit about alternatives to 404 which hopefully explains a bit more, but you are correct, there are a large number of people who think 404 is good too. You will have to research if you want to decide which side are the experts

Comment: To add to the pedantry: technically a PUT should never return 404.  In the absence of an existing resource, the correct behavior is to create a new resource and return 201.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

Comment: I want to vote for the first half but not the second one

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that in the context of the question, your point is exactly right but 'never'?  What about trying to put to resource where the parent resource path does not exist?  I don't think it makes sense to say you must accept a PUT to any arbitrary URI.

Comment: @JimmyJames: If you want full control over exactly what happens, you can always use a POST.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That doesn't address the question.  Are you saying that if a site/API supports PUT on any path, it must support PUT against any arbitrary path?

Comment: @Jimmy: No, that's not what I'm saying.  Arbitrary paths that don't resolve to any identifiable resource are 404's, just like the answer says.  Just like your links illustrate. That's different than a valid path that leads to an empty resource (unknown identifier).

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's what I thought you meant and I agree as I noted in my first response.  It's just that you wrote: "technically a PUT should never return 404" which, if taken literally could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Naturally, if you try to PUT to some arbitrary, non-existent path, it's unlikely you're going to get any meaningful result.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But that's the interesting part, does a 404 make sense there?  The parent resource does not exist and it's (apparently) a user error.  And given that 404 is an allowable substitute for a 403 or 401, it would also seem valid for the scenario you are trying to create something on an existing resource when you don't have rights to do so.

Comment: @JimmyJames: All good evidence that this level of pedantry wrt to HTTP Status Codes merely amounts to mental masturbation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Eh, I'm not so sure.  I think we'd have a lot less problems if people (and especially tool writers) would follow the flippin' spec.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Meh.  [HTTP codes lie anyway](https://lockmedown.com/when-should-you-return-404-instead-of-403-http-status-code/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Returning 404 instead of 403 is spec or maybe I missed your point?

Comment: omg. _this_ is why you just use POST and 200/500. so you never have to have this discussion again

Comment: @Ewan: I'm inclined to agree.  There are many successful API's that just use GET and POST for everything.

Comment: Although... maybe not 500.  More times than I can count, that's an uncaught exception due to bad error handling.  Maybe with a stacktrace spilling out to the user.

Comment: @Ewan "POST and 200/500. so you never have to have this discussion again" Right because that worked so well with the SOAP/WSDL debacle.  500 indicates a server error.  When you return that, you are indicating you have bugs and/or misconfiguration on the server.

Comment: ok 1. yes send the stack trace 2. web services were amazing. 3. once you write a client no-one cares what verb or code you used

Comment: 4. if you are trying to use an api you dont want it not to reply because you used the wrong verb. or have to look up what error code x means. you are trying to make it easy, not obscured by rarely used HTTP codes that kind of fit if you squint at them

Comment: @Ewan "1. yes send the stack trace" I'm sorry, are you saying this is a good idea?  [It's not.](https://owasp.org/www-community/Improper_Error_Handling) "2. web services were amazing." Yes it's 'amazing' is one word you could use to describe the need for an [interoperability standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Interoperability) on top of your interoperability 'standard'. It's also 'amazing' when your 'standard' fails to meet any of it's goals. So basically, you can't be bothered to try to understand the design of the web so you just slop things together and call it a day.

Comment: on the contrary, json and REST is 'slapping things together' proper SOAP with schema and various transmission protocols etc is doing it properly. here we are mucking around arguing about which code is most 'restful' when WCF can do reliable messaging, transactions, multiple protocols etc etc

Comment: @Ewan FYI you can use SOAP with REST but why?  You can also have a schema with [JSON](https://json-schema.org/).  And which 'various transmission protocols' are you talking about?  Are you talking about doing SOAP over something other than misusing HTTP?  That's interesting, if so.  I didn't think anyone really took that idea seriously.

Comment: microsoft took it seriously and still do. WCF is far more powerful than REST. REST is making things easy for people who want to use javascript to make their webpages pretty. Its the easy low featured option

Comment: its crazy to argue about the details of a method which is basically "cramming stuff into the only thing we can do with javascript in a webbrowser". None of it has any technical merit, its all a compromise

Comment: Right, that must be why MS kicked it to the curb.  Because it is so great.  Not because it's outdated bloatware.